# How to replace components with each other in react js?

Tags: reactjs

onClick in login component, I have to display **Home** component and onClick in home component I have to display login component. But Getting this error

```
Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
components) or a class/function(for composite components) but got: object(...)
```

please help me to resolve this.

**Login**

```
handleSubmitValidateInput: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('content'));
    ReactDOM.render(<Home UserDetails={data}/>, document.getElementById('content'));
}
```

**Home**

```
handleLogout: function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('content'));
    ReactDOM.render(<Login />, document.getElementById('content'));
```

But I am able to render both in another component. When I click in **Home** component, I am getting the error.

Answer (score 2):

You definitely need to take a look at https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router to handle the navigation between pages. You should NOT manipulate the DOM directly, since this is against React's way of doing things, since React uses a virtual DOM to keep the state in sync with the real DOM, but that's out of the scope of the question.

The only time you are 'ok' to touch the DOM directly is when you render the whole app for the very first time. Something like this:

`ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById('content'));`

For any additional DOM manipulations, use the data bindings, and let React do its magic.

Comment: No, that is about routing. But I just want to replace components every time when click on something. I am able to going from Login to Home, But I am unable to go from Home to Login by unmounting home and mounting login instead , as I shown in my question